# @Version annotation in spring boot is not working

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I have used the @Version annotation of spring boot, the version field is always null and does not get updated on any updates as well.

**MODEL DEFINITION**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name="REQUEST_TABLE")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestCallBack {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="requestId")
    private String requestId;

    @Column(name="requestName")
    private String requestName;   

    @Column(name="status")
    private int status;
    
    @Column(name="version")
    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

**UPDATE CODE BLOCK**

```
    @Transactional
    public boolean handleRequestCallBack(RequestCallBack requestCallBack){
      
       boolean isStageComplete = false; 
       int completedRequests = 0; 
      
       
       RequestBlockingCallBackRepository.updateRequestBlockingStatus(requestCallBack.getRequestId(),
       requestCallBack.getRequestName(), requestCallBack.getStatus());   
        //   service.update(requestCallBack);
   
       completedRequests = RequestBlockingCallBackRepository.countByRequestIdAndStatus(requestCallBack.getRequestId(),2);
       System.out.println("request "+requestCallBack.getRequestName()+" completedRequests "+completedRequests);

       if(completedRequests==(NUMBER_OF_RequestS)){
        isStageComplete = true;
       
    }
       System.out.println("current stage completed "+isStageComplete);
       return isStageComplete;
    }
```

I am using the h2 db, the version always comes up as null and does not get incremented during any update.

Could someone please help me out here.
Thanks in advance!!

Things I have already tried:

1. setting default value for version
2. maintaing version data type as Long, int, long

Comment: add `Getter` and `Setter` methods  for entity fields.